# linux path added, but the spark is not start

Tags: linux, apache-spark, environment-variables

I added the path for spark bin directory, but when I execute the spark-shell, it did not run.

```
# pwd
/usr/local/spark/bin
# echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/spark/bin

# spark-shell
spark-shell is not found, please check if spark is installed
/usr/bin/spark-shell: line 26: exec: : not found
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is this any vmare or open linux box you are trying to run it .

Comment: but did you add SPARK_HOME to env?